# How to refactor this component to a small one?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, refactoring

How do you suggest refactoring the below code? This has to be run once in the application's lifetime. It has an extended code and useEffect chaining as well.

Is it a good practice to add the resolveUser and syncDatabase functions as actions to the redux store?

```
function App() {
    const {session, syncStatus} = getFromStore();

    const seedDatabase = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            await seeder.seedProductsData();
            await seeder.seedDistributorData();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('seeding failed');
        }
    }, []);

    const resolveUser = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            let user;
            const userRes = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
            user = JSON.parse(userRes);
            if(user){
                user = await fetchUser(user);
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
            setSession(user); // Set Redux state
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('resolve user failed');
        }
    }, []);

    const syncDatabase = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            setSyncStatus('started'); // Set Redux state
            await runSyncProcess();
            setSyncStatus('finished'); // Set Redux state
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('sync database failed');
            setSyncStatus('failed'); // Set Redux state
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const resolveDatabase = async () => {
            if (db.isEmpty()){
                await seedDatabase();
            }
            await resolveUser();
            await syncDatabase();
        }
        resolveDatabase();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(session){
            syncDatabase();
        }
    }, [session]);

    ...

}
```

Comment: Depends on the content of `...` - on what other parts of the app reference the variables declared above

Comment: I think the redux structure could be better and cleaner in this case because you are setting redux state from here, why not use action and setting state in reducer

Comment: @CertainPerformance, based on the loading state and the session it's rendering a spinner or guest/authenticated navigations

Comment: I don't see anything that references "loading" other than your comment - do you mean `syncStatus`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry what I meant was ```syncStatus```.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking to fix, but I'd put it all into a custom hook. Something like `useUserWithDatabase({ session, syncStatus })` and then your App can be free of everything except that custom hook call and `getFromStore`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm looking for a way to refactor the code and make the App component a smaller one. Currently, with all the functions declared in the same component, it's around 1000 lines. So I'm trying to move the code to separate service/action files. A hook is also a great idea. But I'm going to use it only in this component

Answer (score 1):

Just because the long code here is only used in this one App component doesn't mean it can't be put into a custom hook. Creating a custom hook that's only used in one place is a nice pattern I like to follow when the original component would be to cluttered otherwise. For your code, you could do:

```
// should setSyncStatus, runSyncProcess, and others be passed down too?
const useDatabaseWithUser = ({ session, syncStatus }) => {
    const seedDatabase = useCallback(async () => {
        // ...
    }, []);
    
    // ...
    
    // other functions

    useEffect(() => {
        if(session){
            syncDatabase();
        }
    }, [session]);
};
```

and then App would be free of all those functions:

```
function App() {
    const {session, syncStatus} = getFromStore();
    useDatabaseWithUser({ session, syncStatus });
```

If now `useDatabaseWithUser` is too long, you could try splitting it up into more custom hooks according to which functions are most interrelated. It looks like the whole `syncDatabase` call chain may not use anything React specific except for state setter calls and the `useCallback`s for function definitions. If that's the case, you could move them outside of React entirely and pass around the values. For example, in one file:

```
export const resolveUser = ({ setSession }) => {
    try {
        const userDataJSON = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        let user = JSON.parse(userRes);
        if (user){
            user = await fetchUser(user);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
        setSession(user); // Set Redux state
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('resolve user failed');
    }
};
```

and in the caller, import `resolveUser` and pass `setSession` as an argument. It requires some boilerplate to pass everything around, but it'll let you split your code into as many separate files as you want.